# udevでパーミッションを666にする方法は？

Tags: linux, debian

特定のUSBデバイスをroot以外の全員から使えるようにするために、/etc/udev/rules.d に、以下の内容のルールを追加しました

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", MODE="666",　GROUP="usb"
```

（****の部分には適切な値が入っています）
これによって、グループが「usb」、パーミッションが「666」になることを期待しましたのですが、
以下のように、グループが「usb」で、パーミッションが「664」になってしまいます。

```
crw-rw-r-T 1 root usb  189, 147 Feb 19 17:05 020
```

あちこち調べたのですが、MODE="666"を設定すればいい、と書いている解説しか見当たりませんでした。
パーミッションを666にするには何か別の設定等が必要なのでしょうか？
OSは、Debian 7.11です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/` (`/lib/udev/rules.d/` かもしれません) のファイルの方が優先
されている可能性があります。

解決策としては、`/etc/udev/rules.d/00-test.rules` といった感じにファイル名の先頭に
数字2桁を付けていると思いますので、この数字を `99` にしてみてください。
`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-test.rules` というように。

数字を大きくすることで優先されやすくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。91-permissions.rulesで664に設定されていました。